# Map numbers to smallest in a vector of numbers in R

Tags: r, vector

Given a vector of numbers, I'd like to map each to the smallest in a separate vector that the number does not exceed. For example:

```
# Given these
v1 <- 1:10
v2 <- c(2, 5, 11)
# I'd like to return
result <- c(2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
cut(v1, c(0, v2), labels = v2)
 [1] 2  2  5  5  5  11 11 11 11 11
Levels: 2 5 11
```

which can be converted to a numeric vector using `as.numeric(as.character(...))`.

Comment: Thanks! Worth noting that v2 has to be sorted to get the desired behavior (though my question was ambiguous on this front).

Answer (score 2):

Another way (Thanks for the edit [@Ananda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1270695/ananda-mahto))

```
v2[findInterval(v1, v2 + 1) + 1]
#  [1]  2  2  5  5  5 11 11 11 11 11]
```